# Need to write a stored procedure to extract hours from yymmddhhmmss type time stamp in SQL hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, stored-procedures, hive, timestamp

Need to extract calling number of customer during specific time bands  with a stored procedure . Column that has date time is in the format yymmddhhmmss .

```
20181202112658
20181201102326
```

When it was in a DATE Format (11/09/2018 8:19:57 ) I used below to do the above and get the number of calls made during certain hours .

SELECT CALLING_NUMBER,

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(CALL_START_TIME,'HH24') BETWEEN '06' AND '08' THEN CALLING_NUMBER END) AS CDR6_9_COUNT,
SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(CALL_START_TIME,'HH24') BETWEEN '06' AND '08' THEN CALL_DURATION END) AS CDR6_9_DURATION,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `substr()`:

```
SELECT CALLING_NUMBER,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CALL_START_TIME, 9, 2) BETWEEN '06' and '08' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CDR6_9_COUNT,
       . . .
```

If necessary, you may need to convert the value to a string first:

```
SELECT CALLING_NUMBER,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CAST(CALL_START_TIME AS string), 9, 2) BETWEEN '06' and '08' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CDR6_9_COUNT,
       . . .
```

Comment: Thank you so much , but yymmddhhmmss is an integer

Comment: @CharithEllepola did u happen to try the query